# Python: deleting records from a file sequentially with user's choice

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

Why is my program skipping through the names as presented in the output?
I am not extremely familiar with dealing with records, but I can work with them.

I need to add code that will allow me to delete a donor and their number. I ask the user if they want to delete each person as the person is read in.  However, my program is not reading the fields correctly

This is what the original text file looks like ("name:" and "number:"
are not apart of the text file. I put it there to be more specific about format of records.)

name: mike 
number: 5 

name: lee 
number: 0 

name: ramage 
number: 2 

name: james 
number: 6 

name: mack 
number: 10 

More specific on goal:
I want my program to read the name, prompt the user to delete,
if yes, don't write the name or number to temp file (that i will later rename),
if no, write the name and number to temp file.

---

This is the output after running

Would you like to delete mike (y/n)? y 
mike has been deleted 
Would you like to delete  (y/n)? y 
 has been deleted 
Would you like to delete 0 (y/n)? y 
0 has been deleted 
Would you like to delete ramage (y/n)? n 
Would you like to delete  (y/n)? n 
Would you like to delete 6 (y/n)? y 
6 has been deleted 
Would you like to delete mack (y/n)? n

---

```
import os

def main():
    openOriginal = open("donors.txt", "r")
    openNew = open("tempDonor.txt", "w")


    readW = openOriginal.readline()
    while readW != "":

        readW = readW.rstrip("\n")

        readN = openOriginal.readline()


        print(readW)
        print(readN)


        s_ask = input("Would you like to delete " + readW + " (y/n)? ")

        if s_ask != "y":
            openNew.write(readW + "\n")
            openNew.write(readN + "\n")
        else:
            print(readW, "has been deleted")


        readW = openOriginal.readline()

    openOriginal.close()
    openNew.close()

main()
```

Comment: is there a question?

Comment: where are you reading/discarding the empty lines?

Comment: Your input file appears to have a blank line following the name/number pairs, which your code doesn't account for.

Comment: @hop i used rstrip

Comment: `rstrip` doesn't magically make blank lines disappear...

Comment: @JohnGordon that fixed the problem with fields. I do not know if a file holding records is to have spaces in between groups of fields prior to inputting. Is the proper way having spaces between groups of fields?

Comment: the proper way would be to use a proper database. sqlite would be sufficient and is supported by the python stdlib.

Comment: @JohnGordon I still do not completely understand how rstrip works. I can not say with complete confidence that readline() prints "\n", rstrip removes "\n" I feel that's how it works.

Comment: `readline()` returns a line of text which includes the terminating newline at the end.  `rstrip()` removes the newline.  If the line in the file was blank, you will still have an empty string after calling `rstrip()`, which will then get printed or displayed as an empty line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into account the lines that are blank. As it is, your algorithm deals with the data only 2 lines at a time. Modify your algorithm to deal with 3 lines at a time:

`name: james
number: 6
blank line
name: mack
number: 10
blank line
etc..`

Comment: I see. I can do that if i want the spaces between each record in my file. Thank you vm